# System.Data.SQLite asynchronous load problem

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, asynchronous

I'm using `System.Data.SQLite` to query a database with `c#/linq`.
The rows I want to display contain data from various tables. What I currently do is to query one table to get a complete list of items which I place in a DataGrid. Thanks to virtualization I can query the other tables lazily, as the relevant Row comes into view. This works fine.

Now I want to begin filling in the missing data in the rows immediately, but asynchronously. But I get an exception "**DataReader has been closed**" ,  every time I do the lazy loading code in a different thread. Has this to do with the fact that the "original" linq query was done from another thread?

Any idea how I can fix this?

Here is some code that hopefully sums up the problem

```
//Main thread---

//Start the search
_startEvent.Set();
_mainLoadEvent.WaitOne();
_mainLoadEvent.Reset();


//Worker thread---

_startEvent.WaitOne();
_startEvent.Reset();

SearchAllLiterature();  //Fills _searchResults with rows

_mainLoadEvent.Set();   //Signal to mainthread that all rows are loaded

//Fill in some details for every row, that come from various sources, we'll need them later
foreach (var r in _searchResults)
    r.LazyLoadText();


//SearchResultRow.cs

public string Author 
{ 
    get
    {
        LazyLoadText();
        return _author;
    }

    set
    {
        _author = value;
    }
}


//Called by the worker thread or by the DataGrid when a new row comes into view
public void LazyLoadText()
{
    lock (this)
    {
        if (_lazyLoadTextCompleted) return;

        _lazyLoadTextCompleted = true;
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    //this will result in a SQL-query
    var authors = from a in _source.ReferenceOrganization
              orderby a.Person.LastName
              select a.Person;

    Author = ConcatAuthors(authors, sb);

    //...more queries...
}
```

Raising the _mainLoadEvent after the lazy-loading-loop does not show the same problem.

The problem is also solved if I put a static lock around the entire code of the LazyLoad-method. Seems like it is not okay to start queries concurrently, but can this be true?

Comment: Please post some relevant code...

Comment: I added some code to my post. Interesting enough, the problem goes away if the worker-thread sleeps for about 1 s, before starting the lazy loading. I guess this gives the UI enough time to finish the lazy loading of those rows that need to be showed. But why is this a problem? Is my lock-mechanism wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the SQLite data contexts are not thread safe. As the linq-queries where implicitly using the same context I ran into a problem. Using several contexts gets rid of the problem, but unfortunately the contexts have separate caches (or so it seems) so background loading I do one thread won't benefit a later search on another thread. Which basically was the whole idea. 
Loading in the background still is useful if you are not currently accessing the database in the main thread. Although I haven't really figured out an elegant way to determine that.

Comment: The separate cache per thread is not an issue anymore, hasn't been for a while.  Also, parts of Write Ahead Logging introduced in 3.7.0 make multi-threaded and especially multi-process performance better.

Comment: My suggestion for dealing with background loading is to only use one thread for loading.  Have the main thread trigger the background thread to start loading the first record immediately and once it's loaded, pass the data (not data reader, but data, i.e., value object or datatable) back to the main thread.  the background thread can then continue to load in the background.  That said, in my experience sqlite performance is sufficient that background loading is not necessary.  Perhaps you should instead just increase your page size and cache size.

Comment: In what way is the separate cache not an issue? I can measure the difference in searchspeed. I am only loading from one thread. But I also use lazy loading on each row that isn't displayed yet. But it happened that I was still loading in the background and the UI (the other thread so to speak) requested a lazy load as well by accessing a property. Thats where the problems started.

Comment: it's not separate anymore.  I don't remember exactly when it changed, but it's a shared cache now.

Comment: Interesting. Using System.Data.SQLite I could swear there are separate caches by watching the performance of queries on different contexts.

Answer (score -2):

Ok Try Thread.Sleep() before reader closes ;p
I think your 2nd thread is taking long to finish right?...
So if your connection closes before the rest of your data is loaded how is it suposse to work?
You might do something like if(thread2 completed)then complete Main thread...else wait;p

I prolly messed up a bit XD...

I'm not sure if this is your problem...;p sorry if this doesn't help... I've like 5 months 
programming experience:P

Comment: I am not the one who is closing the reader, otherwise I would wait until the second thread has done its work. I think I'm running into another problem. Or did you mean something else?